Enabling minification in debuggable builds for agp >=8.4
Android Gradle Plugin 8.4.0 now displays the following warning/error:
WARNING: BuildType 'r8debug' is both debuggable and has 'isMinifyEnabled' set to true.
Debuggable builds are no longer name minified and all code optimizations and obfuscation will be disabled.


Why does it do that?
How do I tell it to minify my app anyway?

The r8debug build type is specifically for debugging issues with r8.
Obfuscation is disabled for all my builds so debugging did/will work.

The warning is mainly for information. We changed the R8 behaviour at some point to always turn off obfuscation and optimization for debug builds independent of -dontobfuscate and -dontoptimize. We then got bug reports from developers wanting to have a debug build with obfuscation and optimization enabled, but that is no longer possible, and this warning is trying to say exactly that.
You mention that you already had obfuscation disabled for debugability and now you also get optimization turned off for even better debugability (shrinking to remove unused code is still enabled).
In your case you can just ignore the warning.

So minification == code shrinking does take place?

In debug mode isMinifyEnabled only does dead code removal, and no other optimizations. In release mode all optimizations (including obfuscation) are turned on by default.

So it looks like I got confused by the wording. For me, minification equals code shrinking equals dead code removal, but the real meanings seem to differ. The warning states that minification is disabled, however minification seems like the category and only a subset of that category - obfuscation and optimization - are disabled. I'd suggest that you remove the part that debuggable builds are no longer minified and only state that obfuscation and minification are disabled to avoid confusion.

For the next version of Android Gradle Plugin the text has been changed to "BuildType 'minified' is both debuggable and has 'isMinifyEnabled' set to true.\nAll code optimizations and obfuscation are disabled for debuggable builds.". Thank you for letting us know.

Will there a flag to suppress the warning?

Also, I still think that it would be better to state explicitly that dead code removal will still take place

@sgjesse regarding Android libraries,  I have lots of modules libraries, with AGP 8.4 literally stops working. Do I have to -keep all my classes in proguard so they are not shrinked?

If you library modules have isMinifyEnabled = true a change i AGP 8.4 might cause this. Please check https://issuetracker.google.com/338411137#comment13 to see if that is your issue.

So as mentioned by @binarynoise, will there a flag to suppress the warning?

But I want to debug my proguard+reflection issues. How do I do that now, if I cannot obfuscate in debug?

@sgjesse why is the debug build obfuscation no longer available? it is now very difficult to debug a obfuscated build without being able to connect a debugger
